# External drive chmod does nothing

Tags: filesystems, chmod, external-hdd

Why is it that I can do chmod on my files when they are on my laptops hard drive, but when i make files on my external drive, i can't change their access rights.

I do:
chmod 755 somefile,
and on my local drive, the rights change accordingly,
but the very same command does nothing on my external drive.

How comes?

Comment: What filesystem are you using on your external drive?

Comment: The good old 'fuseblk'.

Comment: fuseblk is used to mount NTFS. What is the output for `mount`? Consider changing the filesystem if you only use the drive with Linux.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most probably the filesystem of your external hard drive does not manage or accept change of permissions.

If the filesystem were ext3, ext4, UFS, ZFS or any kind of Unix filesystem you will not have any kind of problems but I guess you are mounting an NTFS or even FAT32 disk. You can check it out with the '*mount*' command.

Comment: It is NTFS in my case; what does that mean? How can I change permissions?